# How to get rid of clothing marks in nude photography?

Tags: nude-photography

**Clothing marks are very annoying in nude/erotic photography** and demand a lot of work to remove them in Photoshop.

How do you get rid of them before starting the session? Do you allow the model to be naked 15 minutes earlier of the session and then dress her again? Do you handle them in post-production?

Comment: Marks on the body are worse when you're dehydrated. If you're in a bind, get them to drink water (although not a [dangerous amount](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/strange-but-true-drinking-too-much-water-can-kill/)) so they're more hydrated, and it should help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe the best way is to allow the model to wear a dressing gown for 15 minutes or so before the shoot. Also ask them in advance to wear loose clothing on the day, to minimise marks as much as possible.

Comment: I was thinking something like giving her a pajama while she's getting her make up.

Comment: same thing, Andres. Though a dressing gown is easier to get on and off while applying makeup to areas away from the face.

Answer (score 8):

Prevention is the best approach. I advise models not to put on anything with elastic or tight at all the day of the shoot. Fifteen minutes in a dressing gown is not enough. A model wearing a slip-on dress and slippers works fine.

Lack of skin elasticity exasperates clothing marks. Staying hydrated also helps the elasticity of skin. Models who are physically fit are generally less susceptible to inelastic skin, as are those who are more youthful.

You can have the model work on the clothing marks with gentle pressure, but that will not produce very quick results and can redden the skin.